# How to resolve rmarkdown to latex errors involving tikz devices

Tags: r-markdown, tinytex, tikzdevice

I am trying to compile an `rmarkdown` document that includes a geographic plot into a PDF file. Here is a MWE:

````
---
title: "Problems with maps in tikz"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
```

## sf:png
Builds find when `nctikz` chunk is excluded.
```{r nc}
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))
```

## sf:tikz
This graphic fails to build.
```{r nctikz, dev = 'tikz'}
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) 
```
````

I am compiling this document using the "Knit" button in RStudio. I'm going to discuss each of the errors / warnings I get when I compile the document in case one leads to the others.

### tinytex

Every time I try to run a chunk that includes `dev = 'tikz'`, `tinytex` will try to reinstall the `pgf` TeX package, then discover it's already there, then give up trying to link it. I'm able to build document with non-geographic `tikz` outputs, however, so I've mostly just accepted this fact.

```
tlmgr search --file --global '/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex'
Trying to automatically install missing LaTeX packages...
tlmgr install pgf
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr install: package already present: pgf
tlmgr path add
add_link_dir_dir: /usr/local/share/info/dir exists; not making symlink.
```

### Invalid characters

Tikz (in knitr) seems unable to handle the degree symbol as part of a tex file. As a note, the `nctikz-1.tex` object can be built by `pdflatex` without issue.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "B0.

Quitting from lines 24-27 (test.Rmd) 
Error: Failed to compile test_files/figure-latex/nctikz-1.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See nctikz-1.log for more info.
```

### Underscore in filepath

I can get around the invalid characters error by suppressing the axis titles `theme(axis.text = element_blank())` on my plot, but this then introduces another error dealing with bringing in a file.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.3975 ...72.27pt,interpolate=true]{nctikz-1_ras1}
                                                  }; 

Quitting from lines 24-27 (test.Rmd)
```

The full line that generates this error is

```
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south west,rotate=  0.00] at (423.16, 120.24) {
    \pgfimage[width= 14.45pt,height= 72.27pt,interpolate=true]{nctikz-1_ras1}};
```

The image it's trying to reference is barely an image (I think it's for the legend).

[image: <code>nctikz-1_ras1.png</code>]

### Environment

I am building this document on MacOS with a whole pile of libraries. In an effort to isolate the issue, I also attempted to build the document on Rstudio.cloud (Ubuntu) in a brand new project. In this environment, only the issue with the math environment / underscore occurs.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.4049 ...72.27pt,interpolate=true]{nctikz-1_ras1}
                                                  }; 

Quitting from lines 26-28 (test.Rmd) 
Error: Failed to compile test_files/figure-latex/nctikz-1.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See nctikz-1.log for more info.
```

Answer (score 3):

Not a full answer, but I would like to document my current state:

1. It makes sense to enable debugging by adding

   ````
   ```{r, include=FALSE}
   options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
   ```
   ````

   to the `Rmd` file [as suggested](https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging).
2. The pgf issue is sort of a red herring. With debugging we see that it happens after some other error occurs (illegal character or underscore in file path). The corresponding regular expression was [recently introduced](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/commit/c124284af9b77f133ce85acc401d7642f0771ab9) and should probably be extended to check for actual error messages from Tikz/pgf.
3. I can reproduce the illegal character on Debian Linux. Somehow `°` is written as `0xB0`, i.e. Latin-1 encoded instead of UTF-8. I am not sure why/where this is happening. BTW, I can process the resulting `tex` file directly with `pdflatex` **only** from RStudio, since that re-encodes the `0xB0` as a question mark. If I use `pdflatex` via Emacs or directly on the command line, I get the same error message.
4. Removing the degree symbol from the output via

   ````
   ```{r nctikz, dev = 'tikz'}
   ggplot(nc) + 
     theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
     geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) 
   ```
   ````

   I can reproduce the "underscore in file path" issue. With debugging turned on, one sees that the issue is again somewhere else:

   ```
   Package pgf Warning: File "nctikz-1_ras1" not found when defining image "pgflas
   timage". Tried all extensions in ".pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:" on input line 3975.

   ! Missing $ inserted.
   <inserted text> 
                   $
   l.3975 ...72.27pt,interpolate=true]{nctikz-1_ras1}
                                                     };
   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
   ```

   The file `nctikz-1_ras1.png` that is present in the same directory as `nctikz-1.tex` is not found. One can reproduce this issue directly using

   ```r
   tinytex::latexmk("<path>/nctikz-1.tex", install_packages = FALSE, clean = FALSE)
   ```

   However, if one changes to the directory first, no such error occurs:

   ```r
   setwd("<path>")
   tinytex::latexmk("./nctikz-1.tex", install_packages = FALSE, clean = FALSE)
   ```

Comment: The problem #2 has been fixed on Github: https://github.com/yihui/tinytex Problem #4 was also fixed on Github: https://github.com/yihui/knitr. I don't know how to fix the encoding issue since it seems to be from the **tikzDevice** package. If the degree symbol is correctly encoded in UTF-8, the .tex file should be correctly compiled.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks for fixing these two issues! I will have a look at the tikzDevice related parts. Good that [Nick Griffiths](https://github.com/ngriffiths21) brought this to your attention.

Comment: Excellent! Perhaps you need more `enc2utf8()` in R (https://github.com/yihui/xfun/blob/cd58c4acf/R/io.R#L40) or `mkCharCE(..., CE_UTF8)` in C (like https://github.com/viking/r-yaml/pull/32/files). I'm not really an expert here, and will leave it to you to figure it out. Thanks!